# How to know if my console solution is inserting data to my db in real time ? Using Logs?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am new to ef core, I have a console solution in .net core which references to a couple of .NET Standard 2.0 class libraries projects.  The `context.SaveChanges` is too long because the app is dealing with huge data.  that's apparently normal, and because of that I need to know if data is currently inserted or not (in real-time) using console logging, I tried Serilog as solution for logging but don't know how to use it for the inserted data ? I am wide open if you have another solution.

Here is a bit of my program.cs :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double pp = 0.8;
    Error error = new Error();
    Cleaner cleaner = new Cleaner();
    Stats stats = new Stats();

    var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                    .WriteTo.Console()
                    .CreateLogger();

    using (var context = new DbWeightWizardContext())
    {
        context.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

        using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
               log.Information("Nettoyage des données en cours... ");
               var pickingsTest = context.PickingTemps.Where(p => p.FLTrait == false).ToList();


                var v1 = cleaner.ClearNullValues(pickingsTest);
                Log.Information("Null values cleared :" + v1.Count());
                var v2 = cleaner.ClearOutliersValues(v1,pp);
                Log.Information("Outliers values cleared :" + v2.Count());
                log.Information("Nettoyage done, Insertion en cours..");

                error.ErrorNullValues(pickingsTest, context);
```

`ErrorNullValues` implements the `SaveChanges` in it so I want to know what does it store in real time before the transaction.commit() ?

Comment: So, you want something written to the console as each record is written?

Comment: yes for each record or foreach 1000 records  because the input db is too huge @Amy

Comment: The question is not really very clear, could you elaborate a bit more ?

Comment: Check out EF Logging https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging, you can also override SaveChanges and log whatever you want.

Comment: A console 1000 times "Row inserted" will be quite unreadable + you won't be able to see the difference between 200 insert and 1000

Comment: Use something with bulk insert capability for faster inserts, or use something that lets you insert records individually for line-by-line updates to the console.  `SqlBulkCopy` is part of .Net Framework.  EF is rather slow.

Comment: I want somthing written to the console in real time as each record is saved (that will be inserted after the commit) just to know that my app is working @MatteoUgolotti

Comment: Just for fast confirmation you can request the Primary before and after the request. This way you don't have your console flooded. But if there is no error on save changes it works.

Comment: yes i already used the bulk insert for one month it is really fast but the extention is not free. thanks @Amy i will try something to record the lines without the logging, but that will make my app slower

Comment: @TALEBSeifEddine `SqlBulkCopy` is absolutely free.

Answer (score -1):

*You can add each record to a **list** after they are created to then be used in a Datatable for the solution below.*

This solution would be to log and export to a *CSV file* which can contain any type of logging as a **DataTable**, this will allow you to set up your own **logging** so you can see the current status of project, here is an example:

ToCSV method:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------String Tool 2-----------------------------------------------------
public static class StringTool2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Get a substring of the first N characters.
    /// </summary>
    // First possible truncate method
    public static string Truncate(string source, int length)
    {
        if (source.Length > length)
        {
            source = source.Substring(0, length);
        }
        return source;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get a substring of the first N characters. [Slow]
    /// </summary>
    // Second possible truncate method
    public static string Truncate2(string source, int length)
    {
        return source.Substring(0, Math.Min(length, source.Length));
    }

    // Method to export (Datatable) to csv
    public static void ToCSV2(this DataTable dtDataTable, string strFilePath)
    {
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(strFilePath, false);
        //Datatable generation
        for (int i = 0; i < dtDataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            //Create comma separated values, retrieving from datatable
            sw.Write(dtDataTable.Columns[i]);
            if (i < dtDataTable.Columns.Count - 1)
            {
                sw.Write(",");
            }
        }
        sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
        // Foreach row in the DataTable
        foreach (DataRow account in dtDataTable.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dtDataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                if (!Convert.IsDBNull(account[i]))
                {
                    string value = account[i].ToString();
                    if (value.Contains(','))
                    {
                        value = String.Format("\"{0}\"", value);
                        sw.Write(value);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sw.Write(account[i].ToString());
                    }
                }
                if (i < dtDataTable.Columns.Count - 1)
                {
                    sw.Write(",");
                }
            }
            sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
        }
        sw.Close();
    }
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

calling and using the method:

```
// Calling the .ToCSV2 method and entering parentheses - Choosing file path and dataTable.
            StringTool2.ToCSV2(dt, "C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Processed\\CloneSuppliersFailed" + DateTime.Now.Hour + DateTime.Now.Minute + DateTime.Now.DayOfYear + DateTime.Now.Month + DateTime.Now.Year + ".csv");
```

You may need to import a few things of which you will need:

```
using System.IO;
using Quartz;
```

This will **create** a .CSV file in your specified location for you to observe, although this isn't real time per say, you can break the code before transaction.commit()  to check the contents of the created file.

Comment: The OP asked how to write a line to the *console* each time a record is written to the database.  This is a lot of code that fails to achieve that goal.

Comment: The OP also was open to other solutions, I stated this in my answer and still believe my answer is a valid solution @Amy

Comment: How does this write a message *as each record is written* to the database?  It does not.

Comment: As each record is written the OP can add the record to a list to be used in a dataTable to be displayed in the file, didn't explain that in my post but will edit accordingly. @Amy